# WPNetwork with custom URL Rewrite rules

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a theme that has some custom rewrite rules built in to it.  The problem is that they are not working with WP multisite.  On the install I use to build themes (which is outside of the network), it works fine.  When I bring the theme into the network, it doesn't work.

**funcitons.php**

```
add_rewrite_rule('^prop/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=prop&mls=$matches[1]','top');

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_mls');

function add_mls($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = 'mls';
    return $public_query_vars;
}
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now, the part that I see that is similar, but not identical is "Wordpress Rule 3", where in my test site, it looks like this:

```
<rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
    <match url="*"/>
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
</rule>
```

So I went ahead and added the rule from my dev site to the network--but I still don't get anything.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I didn't flush the rewrite rules so, or course, the rule wasn't being included.

Second, I ended up going with a MUCH simpler solution to passing the variable to any page with the template applied, which was `add_rewrite_endpoint`.

```
add_action('init', 'my_add_endpoints');

function my_add_endpoints()
{
    add_rewrite_endpoint('myendpoint', EP_PAGES);

}
```

!IMPORTANT - `add_rewrite_endpoint` registers a query var for you and sets that var's value to whatever directly follows it.

So this url:

```
http://mysite.com/mypage/myendpoint/myvalue
```

becomes:

```
http://mysite.com/index.php?pagename=mypage&myendpoint=myvalue
```

It took me two days to eventually figure out what should have already been written in the codex.  I hope this helps whomever comes across it.